# Аналог BitConverter в Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

В C# есть `BitConverter` c методом [`ToInt32`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toint32?view=netcore-2.1).

Есть ли такой же аналог в Kotline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ближайший аналог - [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html). В отличие от `BitConverter` - работает как итератор, поэтому нет дополнительного параметра - позиции начального байта в массиве, а просто можно последовательно вытаскивать из буфера значения одно из другим.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import java.nio.ByteOrder

fun main() {
    val bytes = byteArrayOf(0x33, 0x22, 0x11, 0x00, 0x34, 0x12)
    val buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
    println("0x"+buffer.getInt().toString(16)) // Вытаскиваем 32-битное целое
    println("0x"+buffer.getShort().toString(16)) // Вытаскиваем следующее 16-битное целое
}
```

Вывод:

```
0x112233
0x1234
```

[playground](https://pl.kotl.in/543zqsVNv)

Порядок байт прописал `LITTLE_ENDIAN`, т.к. на платформе x86 используется именно такой порядок (сначала младшие байты, потом старшие), а в `ByteBuffer` по-умолчанию используется `BIG_ENDIAN`.